# MYSQL left join and inner join

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

i have 3 tables

Employee => e_id (P.K), dep_id (F.k)

Department => d_id (P.K)

Attendance => id (P.K), date_of_absence (DATE), e_id_f (F.K)

**i want to get the number of absent employees in certain department for a certain period.**

i created a table called MyDates

```
CREATE TABLE MyDates (mydate date);
```

and this procedure to fill MyDates Table with Dates

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
```

BEGIN

```
  WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
    INSERT INTO MyDates (mydate) VALUES (dateStart);
    SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END;
```

then i called the procedure to fill MyDates with date CALL filldates('2017-01-01','2017-03-31');

Then i made this select statement :

```
select mydates.mydate, count(attendance.date_of_absence)
from mydates left join attendance on
mydates.mydate = attendance.date_of_absence
where mydates.mydate Between "2017-01-01" AND "2017-01-31"
group by mydates.mydate
```

**This query gets what i need but for all departments, BUT for a certain department the number of rows is incorrect**

```
select mydates.mydate, count(attendance.date_of_absence)
from mydates
left join attendance on mydates.mydate = attendance.date_of_absence
inner join employee on attendance.e_id_f = employee.e_id
where mydates.mydate Between "2017-01-01" AND "2017-01-31" AND employee.dep_id = 4
group by mydates.mydate;
```

**This is a screenshot**
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Ird.png)

Comment: can you add what data you need and what result set you are getting in sample form.

Comment: sure, please have a look on the screenshot added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your query I can see. The 1st 2 results in dropping the dates where no matching record is found, the 3rd potentially means that you get wrong counts:

1. `inner join employee on attendance.e_id_f = employee.e_id` - if there is no matching record for a day, then `attendance.e_id_f` will be null for that day. The inner join will eliminate this record from the resultset. Solution: make this join a left as well.
2. `AND employee.dep_id = 4` - this would only keep records in the resultset, that have an employee record associated with it, so if you have a day with 0 absences, this criteria would eliminate it from the resultset. Solution: include this criteria in the join condition.
3. `count(attendance.date_of_absence)` - counts occurances from the attendance table, which will not be correct after adding the 2nd left join. Solution: use `count(employee.dep_id)` instead.

Modified query:

```
select mydates.mydate, count(employee.dep_id)
from mydates
left join attendance on mydates.mydate = attendance.date_of_absence
left join employee on attendance.e_id_f = employee.e_id AND employee.dep_id = 4
where mydates.mydate Between "2017-01-01" AND "2017-01-31" group by mydates.mydate
```

Alternative solution is to use nested joins, where you specifically instruct MySQL to execute `attendance inner join employee` join first. You still need to move the `employee.dep_id = 4` condition to the join condition:

```
select mydates.mydate, count(attendance.date_of_absence)
from mydates
left join (attendance inner join employee)
    on mydates.mydate = attendance.date_of_absence
       and attendance.e_id_f = employee.e_id
       and employee.dep_id = 4
where mydates.mydate Between "2017-01-01" AND "2017-01-31"
group by mydates.mydate
```

In the latter case the nested inner join ensures that only those attendance records are returned that belong to `dep_id = 4` and these records are then left joined to your dates table. In this case there is no need to change the field you are counting.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks a lot Shadow